# How to hover the text in particular column in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tooltip

Trying to hower the text in Name column in react js.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Year      | Name      | Count    |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 2020      | Motor     | 12       |
| 2020      | Nut       | 35       |
| 2020      | Bolt      | 47       |
| 2020      | Engine    | 78       |
| 2020      | Oil       | 125      |
| 2020      | Filter    | 5        |
| 2020      | AC        | 10       |
| 2021      | Motor     | 22       |
| 2021      | Nut       | 76       |
| 2021      | Bolt      | 2        |
| 2021      | Engine    | 5        |
| 2021      | Oil       | 6        |
| 2021      | Filter    | 6        |
| 2021      | AC        | 12       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

```
const columns = [
{
dataField: "year",
text: "Year",
sort: true,
headerAlign: "center"
},
{
dataField: "name",
text: "Name",
sort: true,
headerAlign: "center"
},
{
dataField: "count",
text: "Count",
sort: true,
headerAlign: "center"
}
]
```

New to react js, looking for suggestions how we can hover a text in react table column. Data is receiving from an API.

Answer (score 0):

Install Tooltip Package using this command

```
npm install react-tooltip
```

Or

```
yarn add react-tooltip
```

Now import this package after installation

```
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
```

Now you can use this as like

```
<p data-tip="hello world">Tooltip</p>
```

Don't forget to include  in your component.